# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" when loading image off local server?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pixi.js

I'm trying to load a simple test image from my local host server using the pixi.js library however loading the image results in this error:

```
Access to Image at
'http://localhost:8080/local_files/assests/images/test_image.jpg' from origin 'null'
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present 
on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My code loading the image:

```
//load test image 
var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("http://localhost:8080/local_files/assests/images/test_image.jpg");
```

Comment: It seems you are loading HTML file from local file system? i.e. via `file:///` URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow-origin - generally means that you are allowed to load only resources that are in the same domain you are at. therefore, if you want to load a "localhost" resource, you need to be at localhost.
And yet, in this case, the issue is probably just you trying to load a localhost resource from a remote server that has no access to that local resource.

You need to remember to use images in remote servers. if possible, use the same domain for every resource (image, js file etc). For a static resource, the easiest practice is to use relational paths instead of absolute ones ("./images/image.png" instead of "http://localhost/images/image.png").

I hope this helps

Comment: Actually, different browsers have different Same Origin Policy behavior on local static resource. If relational path is used for image, it works well on Firefox and Safari, but Chrome would still report CORS error.

Comment: @shaochuancs you are correct. however, i gave a general answer as the question was rather general. generally speaking, cross-origin shouldn't be an issue in static assets anyway as they are here to mainly deal with cross-site scripting issue that exists mostly in ajax requests (you can exploit a site using a dynamically created static file, but it's not the case usually). our friend has probably just used the localhost path in mistake instead of using relative paths

Comment: @shaochuancs and sorry, i missed your main point :) i never meant that he keeps using the files at localhost. i recommended him to move his file to the server and address them relatively

Answer (score 0):

If image is loaded from different domain, when the image resource is manipulated by JavaScript (editing etc.), [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is applied.

In this question's case, HTML is loaded from local file system (Origin is `null`) but image is loaded from `http://localhost:8080`. Thus, when pixi.js is used to manipulate image (reading image data and store it as texture), the browser will report error, as `http://localhost:8080` does not support [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

To fix this problem, there are 2 methods:

1. Deploy HTML file on `http://localhost:8080` and load it from there.
2. Enable [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) in `http://localhost:8080`.